# How to stop main wrapping when tangling C in org-babel?

Tags: org-babel, literate-programming

Please consider the following self-contained, minimal example `org` file:

```
#+name: zepto-c
#+CAPTION: A tiny C file
#+begin_src C++ :tangle zepto.c
#include "zepto.h"
void foo (void) {}
#+end_src

#+name: zepto-h
#+CAPTION: A tiny header file
#+begin_src C++ :tangle zepto.h
#include <stdio.h>
void foo (void);
#+end_src
```

On `org-babel-tangle`, it produces the expected two files, `zepto.c` and `zepto.h`, but they contain wrappers with `main`:

zepto.c:

```
int main() {
#include "zepto.h"
void foo (void) {}
return 0;
}
```

zepto.h:

```
int main() {
#include <stdio.h>
void foo (void);
return 0;
}
```

I just want org-babel to tangle out exactly what I wrote, with no modifications. I have tried many combinations of headers `:eval`, `:results`, `:exports`, `:tangle`, and `:noweb` from the documentation, even trying `verbatim` values for them in the hopes that some undocumented feature will give me the results I want, but no luck. The space of all possibile values for those headers is combinatorially large, so it could take me a long time to try them all. Perhaps someone knows the correct incantation?

I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Have you tried `:main no`?

Comment: Well that was easy :-/  I completely missed it in the documentation. Feel free to hoist it to an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `:main` header argument defined in ob-C. `:main no` avoids the wrapping.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also had the problem recently in September 2017. I wish that the default value of :main should be no Do you know how to do that?